# Password becoming unhashed even after saving to database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I have a generic `APIView` where I'm overriding the `create` method. This is for the `Group` model, where I've added a password field:

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password, make_password
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .permissions import AllowOptionsAuthentication
from .serializers import GroupSerializer


class GroupList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset = Group.objects.all()
        serializer_class = GroupSerializer
        permission_classes = [AllowOptionsAuthentication]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        data['password'] = make_password(data['password'])
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

        print(Group.objects.get(name=data['d']).__dict__)  # shows hashed password
        print(serializer.data)  # shows hashed password

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)


class GroupDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowOptionsAuthentication]

    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        try:
            # Grabs the 'name' parameter from the URL
            group = queryset.get(name=self.kwargs['name'])
        except Group.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

        if not check_password(self.request.data['password'], group.password):
            raise Http404

        group.user_set.add(self.request.user)

        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, group)
        return group
```

**serializers.py**

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'password')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.db.models import CharField, Model

Group.add_to_class('password', CharField(max_length=180, null=True, blank=True))
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import GroupList, GroupDetail

urlpatterns = [
    path('groups/', GroupList.as_view()),
    path('groups/<str:name>/', GroupDetail.as_view()),
]
```

**permissions.py**

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


class AllowOptionsAuthentication(IsAuthenticated):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
            return True
        return super(IsAuthenticated, self).has_permission(request, view)
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'djoser',
    'corsheaders',
    # ...
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Inexplicably, after checking both the `serializer.data` and querying the database directly in the above `print` statements, I confirm that I have passed a hashed password into the column. However, whenever I query this afterwards, I see that the raw password has been saved.

I cannot explain how the password is becoming unhashed after saving the hashed password to the database. I am not writing to the `Group` model anywhere else.

But when I query this model after leaving the `create` method:

```
print(Group.objects.get(name='TestGroup').__dict__)  # shows raw password
```

Comment: Can you add how we could reproduce the issue?